# CSS transition image bug with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a weird problem with my CSS/HTML

Here's my code

```css
a:hover {
 color: deeppink;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-out
}

.logo {
 height: 300px;
 margin-top: -100px;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
 transform: scale(1)
}
 
.logo:hover {
 transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
 transform: scale(1.05)
}


.p1 {
 margin-left: 50px
}

.p1::first-letter {
 font-size: 2em;
 font-style: italic;
 font-weight: bold
}

.p dwnld1 {
 margin-top: 3%
}

.contactcontenu {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 5%
 }
```

```html
<html>
 <link href="stylekalaha.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <head>
  <title>Le Jeu du Kalaha</title>
 </head>
 
 <body>
 
  <h1> <img class ="logo" src="images/logoweb.png"></h1>
  
  <div class="bandeau">
   <div class="left"> <a href="index.html"> Projet </a></div>
   <div class="gauche"><a href="regles.html"> Règles </a></div>
   <div class="droite"><a href="download.html"> Téléchargement </a></div>
   <div class="right"> Contacts </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="contactcontenu"> <center>
<form action="mailto:a.bounas@yahoo.fr" name="envoi" method=POST enctype="text/plain">
<table border="0">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <p><b>Nom : </b><input name="nom"size=50 maxlength=50></p>
   <p><b>Prenom : </b><input name="PRENOM"size=50 maxlength=50></p>
   <p><b>Mail : </b><input name="mail" size=50 maxlength=50></p>
   <textarea name="message" cols="60" rows="5"></textarea>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
  <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" name="Envoyer">
  <input type="reset" name="Submit" value="Effacer">
</form>


</center></div>
   <div class="end"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My transition works fine on my others html files but not for this one. When i load the webpage, my `div class=bandeau` is animated, a little swipe from the middle of the page to the top and if my delete my javascript, there is no problem

So how my javascript can affect this html page ? Because the others works fine, my logo is animated like i want
I have the image transition + this transition after the loading, weird ...

Comment: <link>'s generally inside the <head>, certainly not before

Answer (score 0):

Your link tag is not inside the head so your stylesheet isn't getting loaded.

```css
a:hover {
 color: deeppink;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-out
}

.logo {
 height: 300px;
 margin-top: -100px;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
 transform: scale(1)
}
 
.logo:hover {
 transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
 transform: scale(1.05)
}


.p1 {
 margin-left: 50px
}

.p1::first-letter {
 font-size: 2em;
 font-style: italic;
 font-weight: bold
}

.p dwnld1 {
 margin-top: 3%
}

.contactcontenu {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 5%
 }
```

```html
<html>
 
 <head>
        <link href="stylekalaha.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title>Le Jeu du Kalaha</title>
 </head>
 
 <body>
 
  <h1> <img class ="logo" src="images/logoweb.png"></h1>
  
  <div class="bandeau">
   <div class="left"> <a href="index.html"> Projet </a></div>
   <div class="gauche"><a href="regles.html"> Règles </a></div>
   <div class="droite"><a href="download.html"> Téléchargement </a></div>
   <div class="right"> Contacts </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="contactcontenu"> <center>
<form action="mailto:a.bounas@yahoo.fr" name="envoi" method=POST enctype="text/plain">
<table border="0">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <p><b>Nom : </b><input name="nom"size=50 maxlength=50></p>
   <p><b>Prenom : </b><input name="PRENOM"size=50 maxlength=50></p>
   <p><b>Mail : </b><input name="mail" size=50 maxlength=50></p>
   <textarea name="message" cols="60" rows="5"></textarea>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
  <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" name="Envoyer">
  <input type="reset" name="Submit" value="Effacer">
</form>


</center></div>
   <div class="end"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well if your javascript doesn't touch transform or transition then possibly it could be render blocking the html so the css fires before you can see it. Possibly try asyncing the javascript.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my problem, I have an animation on my main logo on my webpage and a javascript. On the others webpage, the logo has a transition and it works. On the webpage with javascript, the logo is animated aswell but during the loading, my webpage has a weird animation and this animation disappear if I delete the animation in my CSS or the javascript in my HTML...

Comment: What is the javascript doing as that is the problem and you haven't provided it.

Comment: Oh yeah... But anyway, I solved the problem with a %margin and not px